# Проблема с кодировкой SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, repository

Пишу на SpringBoot + Hibernate + MySQL

Выполняю код:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String baseUrlRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){

    List<Genre> genreList = genreRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByName("д");

    return "ok";
```

Ничего не находит, хотя в базе есть  имена с буквами "Д"

Когда делаю аналогичный запрос, только с английскими буквами или просто цифрами, то все работает на ура.

сам репозитори:

```
    @Repository
public interface GenreRepository extends JpaRepository<Genre, Long> {
    @Query("select b from Genre b where b.name = :name")
    Genre findByName(@Param("name") String name);
  List<Genre> findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByName(String name);
}
```

Comment: Кодировку исходного кода при компиляции указали?

Comment: Нет, а где указывать нужно? Я просто новичек

Comment: Смотря чем вы компилируете.

Comment: Intelij IDEA + Maven

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать в pom.xml кодировку исходников:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    ...
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: нет, не помогло

Comment: Что MySQL показывает на запрос `SELECT default_character_set_name, default_collation_name
FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name = 'имя_вашей_базы_данных';`?

Comment: utf8mb4-utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Пробовал  все варианты которые нашел, но ничего не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте описать репозиторий так:

```
List<Genre> findByName(String name);
```

без Query у меня все работает

еще как вариант в application.properties
Написать такую строку к Вашему пути:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Ваша_БД?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=true
```